# Rspec expectations failing due to mouse hover over

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

Currently i'm creating an automated test suite using ruby with watir for browser automation and i'm having a small issue with a mouse hover over making my expectation fail because the element cannot be found.

Just to clarify this happens when the mouse isn't anywhere near the browser frame and doesn't happen 100% of the time.

My current expectation looks like this and in my limited experience it should seem to work since the element is still visible on the page:

```
  @browser.ul(class: 'messages').when_present.text.should include "The product has been saved."
```

However then the hover over occurs on the reports tab and expectation fails.
Here's what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ6CD.png

It only happens when dealing with the backend of the sight and i'm wondering if it's just some strange bug since the step definitions seem to also fail when I try to make them skinny but that's another problem.

Has anyone seen anything like this or any ideas?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the mouse hover and the message? For example, it is unclear where the mouse hover is being triggered. It would probably also help to tell us what the failure exception says.

Comment: The expectation passes every time that the hover over / dropdown isn't displayed so I presume it's having an affect since the message which is being expected is displayed on screen still. If you look at the screenshot you can see that the "Reports" drop down is selected even though there's no mouseover in code.
It's throwing a cannot find element exception.